# How do .NAV bot map navigation files in the Steam Workshop work?

Tags: steam, counter-strike-global-offensive

I'm asking because I got these confusing information:

[This map's description](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=128672621) states that the Steam Workshop does not allow including .NAV files and recommends I download a copy from another website, instead. While, this [other Steam Workshop map's description](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=179990737) states that it includes a "unique NAV file".

In the latter map, I checked if there's a .NAV file included with the map in its folder in `\csgo\maps\workshop\`, but there isn't any. However, when I first played that map, the game didn't auto-compute and generate a .NAV bot navigation file before allowing playing with bots, but the bots seem to navigate the map just fine. There still isn't a .NAV file in there after I've played the map. It is possible that this map has included custom-made bot navigation info somewhere.

When I copied the latter map (its folder in `\csgo\maps\workshop\`), to share it with another person who also has CS:GO (but did not download the same map from the Steam Workshop), the game auto-generates a .NAV file when hosting a listen server of that map. This leads me to believe that the custom-made .NAV files of maps downloaded from the Steam Workshop are possibly stored in a location other than `\maps\workshop\`.

**Does the Steam Workshop allow downloading of custom-made bot navigation files (.NAV) along with the map itself?  If yes, where are they located?**

Answer (score 1):

The nav file is likely embedded into the map file using [BSPZip](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Bspzip) or [PakRat](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Pakrat).

This isn't common for Valve's other games, as nav files can be [edited in game](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Navigation_Meshes#Editing_the_navigation_mesh) and embedding it in the map prevents that.  However, workshop restrictions may mean we'll see more of this kind of embedding for CS:GO (and as of August 2015, TF2)

Answer (score 0):

No. You will not get the *.nav file for a map that is not an official map.